# SQL interview- how to get the record if there is no record or count is zero using multiple tables

Tags: sql, sql-server, database, sql-server-2008

I faced an interview and below is the question. The tables are below

Table1: Book (BookId is primary key)

```
BookId  | Book_Title  
1       |   Book1  
2       |   Book2  
3       |   Book3  
4       |   Book4  
5       |   Book5
```

Table2: Book_Copies

```
BookId |    BranchId |  No_of_copies  
1           1           2  
1           2           5  
2           1           0  
2           2           2  
2           3           0  
3           1           0  
3           2           0
```

The output should list all the Books with no stock at all as shown below.

**Output:**

```
Book_Title
---------
Book3  
Book4  
Book5
```

Please note that there are two possibilities. Either the 'No_of_copies' could be 0 or no record for a Book in the "Book_Copies" table.
For e.g.

1. the total number of copies for "Book3" is 0. The output should
   include "Book3"
2. the total number of copies for "Book1 and "Book2" is 7 and 2
   respectively. Both "Book1" and "Book2" shouldn't display
3. there is no entry for Book4 and Book5 in "Book_Copies", so both
   should be included in output

After coming home, I wrote the below query after so many trials :)

```
select B.Book_Title  
from  
(  
  select BC.BookId, sum(BC.No_of_copies) as 'No of copies'  
  from Book_Copies BC  
  group by BC.BookId  
  having sum(BC.No_of_copies) = 0  
  union   
  select B.BookId, BC.No_of_copies  
  from Book B  
  left outer join Book_Copies BC on B.BookId = BC.BookId  
  where BC.BookId is null  
)  
as BookIds_withNoStock   
inner join Book B on B.BookId = BookIds_withNoStock.BookId
```

This query works fine and tested properly.
Is there any way we can improve this query? like complexity, performance etc
If we can improve it, it would be helpful if you can provide the optimized query and reason. Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try This

```
SELECT B.Book_Title
From Book B LEFT JOIN book_copies BC ON B.Bookid = BC.Bookid
Group By B.Book_Title 
Having SUM(ISNULL(BC.no_of_copies,0)) = 0
```

**[FIddle Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/4da44/2)**

**Output:**

```
BOOK_TITLE
Book3
Book4
Book5
```

Answer (score 3):

You want books with no stock.  I would approach this with a `left outer join`, aggregation, and a `having` clause:

```
select b.bookid, b.book_title
from book b left join
     book_copies bc
     on b.bookid = bc.bookid
group by b.bookid, b.book_title
having coalesce(sum(bc.no_of_copies), 0) = 0;
```

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
select Book_Title from Book left join Book_Copies on Book.BookId = Book_Copies.BookId 
group by Book_Title having 
 SUM(Book_Copies.No_of_copies) IS NULL OR SUM(Book_Copies.No_of_copies)=0
```

Comment: also include `BookId` in Grouping ,as u said ID is `PK`, there may be same book name with different ID's..

Answer (score 0):

The below code worked for me:

```
SELECT a.Book_Title 
FROM #books a
    left join(
                SELECT BookId,sum(No_of_copies) Cnt
                FROM #Book_Copies
                GROUP BY BookId) b
        ON a.BookId = b.BookId
WHERE b.cnt = 0 OR b.Cnt is null
```

Answer (score 0):

```
select book_title
from books
where book_id NOT IN 
(
   select book_id
   from book_copies
   group by book_id
   having sum( no_copies) > 0
)
```

Comment: Care to explain your improvements?